# Sample space for 3 cards chosen from a deck containing 3 red, 3 blue, 3 green, and 3 black ones.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Three non-replaced cards are randomly selected from a deck containing $3$ red, $3$ blue, $3$ green, and $3$ black cards. Specify a sample space for this experiment

I think there are $220$ combinations.

So I have to write the sample space with $220$ ways? Or there is another way to write it?

Comment: Why do you think it is 220 ?   (Ie express it as $\binom{12}3$ because ....)

Comment: because the are combinations of n elements taken from k to k so its $\frac{n!}{k!*(n-k)!}$

Comment: Depends on if RRB is the same as RBR or if they are different. Also, I think the red balls are indistinguishable, So $R_1 B_1 B_1$ is certainly the same as $R_2 B_1 B_3.$ Otherwise the colours wouldn’t have been a part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

If cards for the same color are indistinguishable, we can break down the card selection into three different cases:

1. Three cards are from the same color: $C_1^4=4$ ways.
2. Two card are the same color, the third one is from a different color:
   $C_1^4C_1^3=12$ ways.
3. Three cards  are from different colors: $C_3^4=4$ ways.

Total sample space:4+12+4=20.

If the cards  for the same color  are distinguishable, the total sample space is $C_3^{12}=220$ as expected in the question.